# setColumnFilterCriteria test issues Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document. What am I missing?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I'm attempting to programmatically set a filter on a Google Sheet.

Pulling code from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setColumnFilterCriteria(Integer,FilterCriteria), I try to execute this function:

```
function FilterTest() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let filter = ss.getFilter();
  // Builds the filter criteria to use as a parameter for setColumnFilterCriteria.
  const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                             .setHiddenValues(["Done", "Skip"])
                             .build();
  // Sets the filter criteria for column A.
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
  }
```

Upon execution, the result I'm getting is:
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ...

The error occurs when the script is attempting to execute the last line, "filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);".

The Project OAuth Scope is "https://www.googleapis.com/autht/spreadsheets"

What am I overlooking?  Is there some prerequisite authorization or add-on I'm missing?

Thank you and fair winds.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample sheet so that we can replicate the issue? As well as try to create a duplicate version of the sheet and test or run the script in a different spreadsheet as well. Also check the permissions of the sheet if it is set to Anyone with the link can edit.

Comment: @Century Tuna Here is a link to a sample sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17mJfaxmWPGPirk-rG_Qp_95yHi-wba9xDeURg3O3bpM/edit?usp=sharing  There is a menu item to execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution / Suggestion**

Seems like a server-side issue that can be fixed by removing and adding the filter again on your sheets. Already fixed what you shared:

[image]

I went a bit further and checked all possible sources, from Google's Issue Tracker and all, but it seems that most of these scenarios are only transient errors. If this happens again and the solution above doesn't work, make sure you file a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Wow!  That did it.  Unbelievable.  Thank you SO MUCH for taking the time to look into this for me.  I was at my rope's end.  I had code that was working for years to perform this function.  Then, a couple of month's ago, it simply quit working with the error presented above.  I spent many hours researching and trying different things, but I never simply deleted my existing filter and added it back.  The sheet in the sample i sent you was created by taking my existing sheet and deleting  everything I could think of that wasn't relevant to the problem EXCEPT for the preexisting filter itself.